# Adding serialization information for MongoDB custom serializer

Tags: c#, serialization, mongodb-.net-driver, querying

I have a class defined as follows:

```
class Person
{
  public String Id { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
  public Person Mother { get; set; }
}
```

I've implemented a custom serializer for the Mother property to serialize the Id only. The final BSON would look something like this:

```
[{
   "_id": "54df1095fa0bd7122cb2c550", 
   "name": "John", 
   "mother": { "_id": "54df1095fa0bd7122cb2c551" }
}]
```

If I try to execute a query to find a person with a given mother as follows:

```
var results = await collection.Find<Person> (p => p.Mother.Id == "...").ToListAsync ();
```

The driver complains with the following:

{"Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression: p.Mother.Id."}

Is there a way to add serialization info to the driver so it knows to call my custom serializer to deserialize Person for this type of query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are two interfaces you may implement to provide serialization information. `IBsonDocumentSerializer` and `IBsonArraySerializer`. In this case, you'll want to implement `IBsonDocumentSerializer` on your customer serializer and handle the `GetMemberSerializationInfo` call for the memberName `Id`.